# python look-and-say sequence improved

Tags: python, sequences

I would like to introduce look-and-say sequence at first. It goes like `a = {1, 11, 21, 1211, 111221 ...`

The system is it checks the previous digit and counts the numbers.

`1 = one 1 (so = 11)

11 = two 1 (so = 21)

21 = one 2 one 1 (so = 1211)`

As a rule of the sequence, no number can go beyond 3, so creating a translation table can fit in. But it is not semantic, I don't like it.

What I want is, a script which evaluates the given value and return a look-and-say-alike string.

However, to go beyond out limits, I want it to even evaluate chars, so it can return `1A2b41`.

I have been trying to make it work for hours, the logic went bad and I am having a brainfreeze at the moment.

Here is the script that actually doesn't work(returns false results), but it can give you the idea, at least.

```
def seq(a):
    k,last,result,a = 1,'','',str(a)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if last==a[i]:k+=1
        else:
            result = result+str(k)+a[i]
            k=1
        last = a[i]
    return result
```

Comment: "What I want is, a script which evaluates the given value and return a look-and-say-alike string.". To be more clear. I want a function that evaluates the next value of the look-and-say sequence, with the features describe on the main post.

Comment: Just so you know, I've always found it more helpful in the long run to debug my own code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see two issues with your code:

- The `result` is expanded by `k` and `a[i]` although the counter `k` does not count chars `a[i]` but chars `last`. Replace `a[i]` by `last` here (you may not want to add anything in the first round).
- After the loop you have to add the last value of the counter together with the last character again (this was not yet done), i.e. add another `result = result+str(k)+last` after the loop.

In total it looks like

```
def seq(a):
    a = str(a)
    k,last,result = 1,a[0],''
    for i in range(1,len(a)):
        if last==a[i]:k+=1
        else:
            result = result+str(k)+last
            k=1
        last = a[i]
    result = result+str(k)+last
    return result
```

Comment: I had both tried with `last` and `a[i]`, but the main problem was i did not set a `result` after the loop. Thanks for the help.  BUT, the code is still returning invalid results. e.g. `seq('AAABBC')` returns `'2A2B1C'`.

Comment: @fastreload sorry, my fault - see my edit. Of course python uses zero-based indices.

Comment: Works well now. Thank you, all of the 3 answers are actually correct, but I choose yours because it is the most similar to my code.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `groupby`, it's just what you want:

```
from itertools import groupby
def lookandsay(n):
    return ''.join( str(len(list(g))) + k for k, g in groupby(n))

>>> lookandsay('1')
'11'
>>> lookandsay('1A2b41')
'111A121b1411'
>>> lookandsay(lookandsay('1A2b41'))
'311A1112111b111421'
```

`groupby` returns consecutive keys and groups from an iterable object. The key is a function computed for each element, or an identity function if not specified (as above). The group is an iterator - a new group is generated when the value of the key function changes. So, for instance, according to the documentation:

```
# [k for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCDAABBB')] --> A B C D A B
# [list(g) for k, g in groupby('AAAABBBCCD')] --> AAAA BBB CC D
```

Comment: This is a good way to do it but doesn't help him understand why he's having problems or what his problems are.

Comment: Agreed. Howard has covered the errors in OP's code pretty extensively, I don't think I have anything to improve upon his answer except an alternative solution.

Comment: I can see that `groupby` allows us to this very well, but i need to understand how and what is does, starting now =).

Comment: I added a short description. Check the Python documentation if you need more detail.

Answer (score 4):

I think part of why you got stumped is your use of meaningless variable names. You described the problem quite well and called it by name, but didn't even use that name for your function.

If you think of the string you start with as "look", and the one you end up with as "say", that is a start. `result` is probably fine but `a` and `k` have confused you. `last` is, I think, misleading, because it can mean either previous or final.

Also, Python's `for` is really `foreach` for a reason -- you're taking each character in the "look" one at a time, so do it explicitly in the loop.

```
def looksay(look):
    look = str(look)
    prev, count, say = look[0], 1, ''
    for char in look[1:]:
        if char == prev:
            count += 1
            continue
        say += str(count) + prev
        prev = char
        count = 1
    return say + str(count) + prev
```

The spacing is less important, but Python does have a [standard coding style](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), and it does help readability to use it. The less mental time you have to spend parsing your code, the more focus you have for the problem.

Comment: To be honest, I was trying to solve a puzzle therefore i did not explicitly defined variables and I have spent so much time with this snippet that the variables names did not matter much. In real programming, I do not do that at all.  Code snippet works flawless. Just to clarify: `continue` statement skips the lines below and jumps to next step in the for loop, right?

Comment: Yes. You could put the rest of the loop in an `else` instead, but if you want to skip everything below a point I think it's better to use `continue` because it's explicit that that's what you're doing. It also avoids having to indent code another level that is really the main body of the `for` loop. I know it _feels_ like the variable names, style, etc. don't matter, but they do actually get in the way of seeing through to the algorithmic problems with your code. Especially when you have problems with something, you should take the time to be as explicit and clear as possible; it will help.